How to trim spaces without expanding what is inside in expl3?
Consider the following pattern:
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}{
    \myinternalcommand:n{#1}
}
\cs_new:Nn \myinternalcommand:n{
    \tl_if_single:nTF{#1}{TRUE}{FALSE}
}

and let's say that I want to do different things depending on whether \mycommand gets a control sequence or not as input: \mycommand{\mycs} should do one thing, and \mycommand{abcde} should do another thing. I would like in particular \mycommand{   \mycs   } to work.
My question is: how to use \tl_trim_spaces to trim spaces around control sequences... without expanding the control sequence? (in the pattern above, the :n form of the arguments can be changed)
Note: even if this application is bad (in that case, I would like to know why), I'm still interested in the original question: how to trim spaces without expanding what is inside?

Perhaps yuo should explain how space triming is related here?

BTW, \myinternalcommand:n isn't internal, it's code-level and should be documented ...

As you are creating a document command, one would typically use the ltcmd processor interface:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand { > { \TrimSpaces } m }
  {
    \myinternalcommand:n {#1}
  }

If you want to trim spaces at the code level, as described in interface3 you can rely on the fact that \tl_trim_spaces:n prevents further expansion, thus for example
\cs_new:Npn \my_pkg_fn:n #1
  {
    \use:e { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} }
  }
\my_pkg_fn:n { ~ \foo }

will leave exactly \foo in the input stream.
From the question, it seems you'd want to do something like
\cs_new:Npn \myinternalcommand:n #1
  {
    \myinternalcommand_aux:e {#1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \myinternalcommand_aux:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_single:nTF{#1}{TRUE}{FALSE}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \myinternalcommand_aux:n { e }

though that does really feel like you are worrying about document level input spaces ...

Thanks! So that I visualize better how to use the thing at the code level, could you show how to transform the line of \myinternalcommand:n{#1} with the \use:e { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} } so that the internal command receives a trimmed argument ?

Why not \cs_new:Npn \myinternalcommand:n #1 { \tl_if_single:eTF { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} } { TRUE } { FALSE } }?

@Skillmon I assume the real use case does something further with the token(s), so I'm anticipating that we want to trim just once

@JosephWright Where can I find the documentation of the syntax of ltcmd? Does \TrimSpaces apply to all parameters or the fist one after?
